# Zxing scan result on new Activity

Tags: android, zxing, scanning

I have added Zxing 3.0.1 as a library to my project I have 2 layouts: on first i have button which call **CaptureActivity**  of Zxing library, and when **CaptureActivit**y decode a barcode i need to put this code on a second layout into *textView*. How can i do this? If someone know, please write step-by-step manual, because in and Android beginner, and dont know what to code .

I must put something this part of code **CaptureActivity**?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  if (requestCode == HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE) {

    int itemNumber = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.History.ITEM_NUMBER, -1);
    if (itemNumber >= 0) {
      HistoryItem historyItem = historyManager.buildHistoryItem(itemNumber);
      decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(null, historyItem.getResult());
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: your question isn't clear. what do you mean by 2 layouts? Did you mean to say 2 activities, one with a button and one with textview?

Comment: The answer depends on if you you want to go back to the previous activity with the result or if you want to start a new activity with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Yout have to start CaptureActivity with **startActivityForResult**:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class), CaptureActivity.REQUEST_CODE);
```

When Zxing done with decoding (in my case it return it's result in **handleResult(Result rawResult)** callback- you should call **setResult(RESULT_OK, data)** inside CaptureActivity where data - is your decoded bundled string and call **finish()**:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    args.putString(RESULT_KEY, rawResult.getText());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
}
```

In Activity which started CaptureActivity you have to override **onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)** callback and handle getting result - in your case - update a TextView:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
   if (requestCode == CaptureActivity.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       youtTextView.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               yourTextView.setText(intent.getStringExtra(RESULT_KEY));
           }
       };
   }
}
```

Comment: On my MainActivity i add a button with method onClick(where i start CaptureActivity with startActivityForResult).I still dont understand what code i must put in CaptureActiviti, and what i need to write in my MainActivity in method onActivityResult

Comment: @Kirill,  will update my answer with code from my app shortly.

Comment: i didnt understand code of **CaptureActivity** where zxing done with decocing there? where i must put handkeResult?